# Generate & Display QR using Nodemcu on TFT Display ST7789 240*240

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, display, tft

I have NodeMCU & ST7789 TFT display. I want to generate QR Code of any dynamic input and display it on my TFT display. Not able to find any suitable reference. All Standard QR code libraries only work for Arduino & not for NodeMcu, board not supported for them. Can someone please help ?

Libraries Tried :
https://github.com/yoprogramo/ESP_QRcode
https://github.com/anunpanya/ESP8266_QRcode
https://github.com/ricmoo/qrcode
https://github.com/onelife/rtt-qrcode

Comment: I suspect the real question is why does the Arduino QR library not work for the Nodemcu?  Also, post a link to the QR library you are intending to use just to make things clear.  Lastly, to make the project easier - you may want to constrain the code to a fixed length or at least limit it.  I have see QR codes on the sides of trucks so complex they look like sand grains.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I tried all existing libraries : https://github.com/yoprogramo/ESP_QRcode , https://github.com/anunpanya/ESP8266_QRcode, https://github.com/ricmoo/qrcode/, https://github.com/onelife/rtt-qrcode, But they all seems to dont seem to work with NodeMCU. Can you correct me if I am wrong, or if you have a work around. I dont require very complex QR Code (Grainy), simple usual ones, that we we see around.